# why doesnt my post container work?

Tags: html, css, post, containers

My html or css is not working and the container doesnt work i should be seeing a green bar under the image but no. i think that since its on auto it doesnt recognize that there is stuff in that div could you guys help me out?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbXSB/)

Html

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main2.css">
</head>
<body>

   <div id="content">

        <div id="postcontainer">
            <div id="postpicture">
                <img src="" width="80px" height="80px">
            </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div id="postheader">
                        <div id="postname">
                            Sean Allen
                        </div>
                        <div id="postdate">
                            July 15, 2013
                        </div>
                    <div id="post">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
html, body {
Padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background:#EDEDED;
}

#content{
width:900px;
height:auto;
min-height:1000px;
background:#FFFFFF;
}

#postcontainer{
width:auto;
height:auto;
background:green;
}

#postpicture{
width:80px;
height:80px;
float:left;
padding:8px;
border:2px solid #FFFFFF; 
outline:1px solid #AAAAAA;
background:yellow;
}

#right{
width:800px;
height:auto;
float:right;
background:blue;
}

#postheader{
width:790px;
height:auto;
background:red;
}

#postname{
width:auto;
height:19px;
padding:5px;
padding-top:10px;
font-weight:600;
float:left;
background:brown;
}

#postdate{
width:auto;
height:19px;
padding:5px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:13px;
float:left;
font-size:13px;
background:purple;
}

#post{
width:785px;
height:auto;
padding-left:15px;
float:left;
background:orange;
 }
```

Comment: heres a preview of it http://jsfiddle.net/XCyfR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't cleared `#postcontainer` - which is needed because it has floated descendants (which are taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)) - one remedy is to add `overflow: hidden;` so that it creates a new block formatting context for its floated descendants and `height: auto;` will then work like you'd expect. Remember that a floated element is not acknowledged by other block-level elements in the normal flow (read the above link if you don't understand), unless you [clear](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing) it or provide a new [block-formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for its parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/ANhUn/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block;` in `#postcontainer`.

http://jsfiddle.net/cc48D/